# Data Migration within Apache Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, bigdata, solrcloud

Good afternoon!
I would like to know, please, how can I do the Data migration in Apache Solr? Is that possible?
For example:
I am currently working with a collection of Data (a large amount of Data) and I want to do the following:
Pass my Data from "COLLECTION1" to "COLLECTION2", for example. Is that possible?

Thank you so much, guys!

Comment: something like "restoring a backup"?

Comment: Hi [Olaf Kock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13447/olaf-kock)!                                         
So, I actually want to do a backup of my Datas or migrate this Data to another collection (like: there would be two collections in Solr, where one of which would be to have only my "Saved" Data).   Thank you so much!

Comment: I think the following documentation will help me:  https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/making-and-restoring-backups.html#backuprestore-storage-repositories